# Get SSE version without __asm on x64

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, sse, cpuid

I'm trying to build slightly modified versions of some functions of the VS2010 CRT library, all is well except for the parts where it tries to access a global variable which presumably holds the instruction set architecture version (ISA):

```
if (__isa_available > __ISA_AVAILABLE_SSE2)
{
    // ...
}
else if (__isa_available == __ISA_AVAILABLE_SSE2)
{
    // ...
}
```

The values it should hold I found in an assembly file

```
__ISA_AVAILABLE_X86   equ 0
__ISA_AVAILABLE_SSE2  equ 1
__ISA_AVAILABLE_SSE42 equ 2
__ISA_AVAILABLE_AVX   equ 3
```

How and where `__isa_available` is assigned a value is nowhere to be found (I've tried a find-in-files in all my directories...)

MSDN refers to the [CPUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6aek1h.aspx) example to determine the instruction set. The problem with that is it uses `__asm` blocks and those are not allowed in my x64 build.

Does anyone knows how to quickly assign the correct value to `__isa_available`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft decided to stop the support of inline assembly. But they introduced a new format. You can find more information about CPUID in the new format [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?view=msvc-170) (with example).

The advantage of intrinsics over inline assembly is that they are compatible with both x86 and x64 without additional code and are easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

VC++ has an intrinsic that allows you to use CPUID without inline ASM:

[__cpuid in intrin.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?view=msvc-170)

On that same website is an extensive code sample, too.